# How to compute masked VGG loss

Tags: python, deep-learning, pytorch, conv-neural-network

I have `gt` and `pred` images and wish to compute VGG loss only on a subset of pixels given by `mask`. `mask` has same spatial resolution as `gt` but the ON pixels are not in any regular geometry. How to achieve this? Please note that loss is computed over a deeper layer of VGG so the activation maps resolution will be smaller than `gt`.

One possible solution which I can think of is,

```
gt[~mask] = const
pred[~mask] = const

torch.nn.functional.mse(VGG(gt), VGG(pred))
```

I believe since non masked pixels have been artificially made of same value, the gradients due to a mismatch on these pixels will be 0.

Is this the correct way to compute a masked VGG loss?

Answer (score 1):

What you suggested makes sense from a code perspective. I'm assuming `pred` is a generated image and you want to backprop gradients through the model that produced it.

Now you have to think about whether that's really what you want to do. VGG loss is a *perceptual* loss, designed to make `pred` and `gt` *look* similar to a pretrained VGG network. If you mask out regions of the inputs, you can only speculate about what that VGG loss will do (considering it's likely never seen such data during its training).

If you really want to use a VGG loss, I would recommend you re-train VGG yourself, masking out inputs. Ideally with a mask distribution that looks like what you'll get during your generation task.

https://paperswithcode.com/method/vgg-loss